facing issue in reading the email from office365
We are creating the process to auto read the unread emails from inbox. Process is working fine with our and other domains mail server but when we are using the client email address (office365 email server) not working. We have tried with app genearted password as well with the generate the key for application but no success. We have tried the package of limilab and AE.Net.Mail.
    using (var imap = new ImapClient(_importEmailSettings.Host, _importEmailSettings.Email, _importEmailSettings.Password, AuthMethods.Login, 993, false,true))

{
    var msgs = imap.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen());

   
    imap.SetFlags(AE.Net.Mail.Flags.Seen, uid.Value);

}
If we set the ssl true then get this error message

If we set ssl false then get this error message


According to the error message , it seems you have using the wrong password, how about using the same password in workable machine?

I am guessing it is more of a networking issue. Either your application can't see the server hosting the email, or that email server is actively rejecting it. Perhaps check whitelists and such from the email server? Are you able to access the email login from something else that isn't a web browser?

using the password, able to login on browser. And using the app generated also, email sent working but issue in reading the email.
